# Linux PostgreSQL backup single schemas + data into individual files

Tags: postgresql, backup, linux

Is there a way to backup only the schemas (plus their relative data) of a PostgreSQL DB individually, into single dedicated files?

I'm on Linux CentOS 7, hopefully there's some way to automate this so I can make a cronjob and run the backups when I want!

I know [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), I've checked and with it I think I can make a single file backup of all the schemas + data with this command:

```
pg_dump dbname -n -f backup.sql
```

but what I want is different, I want to separate all the schemas + data of the DB in single files. I have no idea how to achieve that with pg_dump... maybe using bash too? But I have no idea, I have never used bash in my life.

```
--schema=PATTERN         dump the specified schema(s) only
```

I think that still saves everything into one single file.
Also, I don't want to specify all the schemas by hand, as they are a lot... I need them all, so I don't think I have to use `--schema=PATTERN`, right?

Comment: `--schema=PATTERN         dump the specified schema(s) only`

Comment: thanks... but I think it still saves everything into one single file. 
Also, I don't want to specify all the schemas by hand, as they are a lot... I need them all, so I don't think I have to use "--schema=PATTERN", right?

Comment: You'll have to script that: first, query for all the schemas you care for, then run a `pg_dump` for each of them.

Comment: Yeah I've solved that with a small script, wasn't as hard as I thought... I was a little bit scared by the other big scripts in multiple files I've seen online ahah, thank you both!